# Can i access different database in django than other default database

Tags: python, database, django

I have the database backup script in python which inserts  some data in mysql database .

Now my Django is in different database.

How can i access different database because i don't have any objects in Models.py.
i want to display some data in django interface

Comment: Which version do you use? If it's 1.3, check out Dantario's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can setup multiple database and access every one of them.
you can get the specified database connection cursor using this:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
```

where `my_db_alias` is your another db alias .

check the doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: will that work if i don't have models for those in models file. That database is used by separate application so there is no relation of django with it . ijust want to read stuff.

Comment: yes, you can. I edited my answer to show you how to get the raw connection cursor.